# valid json response with Postman but Invalid response with https module

Tags: node.js, https, postman, linkedin-api, voyager

I am calling this endpoint

`https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/typeahead/hitsV2?keywords="sousse tunisia"&origin=OTHER&q=type&queryContext=List(geoVersion-%3E3,bingGeoSubTypeFilters-%3EMARKET_AREA%7CCOUNTRY_REGION%7CADMIN_DIVISION_1%7CCITY)&type=GEO`

With Postman I get a valid json response. but when I call the same endpoint using https module in node.js code, I get an invalid json response with status 200.
the invalid response is something like this `�������Q�[@��=��M�x��Ik�CzEa:H`

I am using the accept header like this: `_headers['accept']= 'application/vnd.linkedin.normalized+json+2.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the other endpoint used a gzip encryption. but this endpoint doesn't.
so I just set the **accept-encoding** to empty **_headers["accept-encoding"] = ""**. It was confusing that even with the wrong encoding postman showed a correct response.